# prestashop create a cart and add a product programmatically

Tags: php, prestashop

I am trying to create a simple task as follows:

1. Write a custom controller

2. create a cart if it is not created

3. add a product to the cart

[came accross this code that is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24610116/5170117).

I need to know a few things:

1. In which folder should i place my custom controller?

2. Which parent controller class should my controller extend?

3. what will be the url for the controller?

Comment: please explain your requirement in more detail that will help to give a good  answer

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when you want this action to happen. Like always with prestashop, you have 2 possibilities :

### Override an existing controller

For example if you want to add a product to the cart everytime its created, you might want to override CartController. In that case here is the answers to your questions :

1. In the `override/controllers` folder.
2. The parent controller you chose, for example CartControllerCore
3. The same as the parent controller. [Check the official doc about the dispatcher](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/The+Dispatcher), it's pretty usefull

### Create you own module

I think this is the best choice if you want to have a real control over when you trigger this action.

1. In the modules/you_module/controllers folder. [The official doc](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+PrestaShop+Module) is also a great place to start.
2. ModuleFrontController
3. Refer to the page about the dispatcher I gave you above, but the best way to trigger your action is to use the hook system.